# Problem with zero epsilon value for Kalman filter

Tags: kalman-filter

I am coding a Kalman filter in R and I am trying to estimate the parameters dV and dW using the methods as provided in [Vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlm/vignettes/dlm.pdf) section2. However I get Epsilon=0 (which is dV for Kalman filter) for my ts data. I am not sure how we get a non-zero dV for the Nile data (available in R) used in the example in [1](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlm/vignettes/dlm.pdf). Can somebody explain what dV means as it is not the same as var(z)?

```
> dput(z)   # my time series data
structure(c(4341, 3426, 2312, 2118, 2003, 1881, 1734, 1764, 1634, 
1649, 1316, 1191, 1145, 1094, 1118, 1107, 1145, 1087, 1071, 1056, 
1075, 984, 925, 963, 916, 873, 836, 837, 903, 924, 847, 863, 
874, 872, 926, 1017, 1274, 1306, 1334, 1240, 1971, 2620, 2803, 
2701, 2846, 2728, 2597, 2440, 2673, 2588, 2578, 2899, 3129, 3100, 
4244, 5175, 6409, 7444, 7732, 5847, 4483, 3350, 2907, 2626, 2162, 
2151, 1628, 1575, 1353, 1443, 1150, 1161, 1122, 1147, 1173, 1026, 
966, 925, 980, 1002, 939, 1010, 958, 1141, 1138, 1112, 1029, 
1369, 1878, 1478, 1694, 2065, 2635, 2438, 2539, 3099, 3014, 2825, 
2610, 2972, 2911, 3508, 4579, 5421, 4382, 3997, 3927, 4116, 4122, 
3696, 3793, 3607, 3386, 2817, 2293, 2101, 2111, 1933, 1769, 1694, 
1711, 1560, 1428, 1322, 1286, 1346, 1174, 1006, 1031, 997, 1066, 
1071, 1015, 1064, 1004, 1003, 992, 1095, 1161, 1252, 1416, 1495, 
1649, 1918, 1913, 1959, 2341, 2609, 2952, 2918, 2684, 2836, 2873, 
3205, 3078, 3510, 3524, 3126, 2685, 3213, 4183, 5710, 5925, 6565, 
5543, 4649, 3324, 2673, 2156, 1899, 2175, 1892, 1693, 1539, 1411, 
1381, 1339, 1385, 1359, 1336, 1310, 1178, 1204, 1186, 1224, 1200, 
1209, 1308, 1212, 1172, 1323, 1495, 1580, 1758, 1743, 2019, 2267, 
2363, 2522, 2680, 2889, 2894, 2386, 2934, 2908, 2615, 2434, 3022, 
4408, 4546, 4965, 7135, 9531, 9758, 8440, 7945, 6356, 4819, 4100, 
3085, 2694, 2202, 2023, 1828, 1812, 1518, 1404, 1427, 1361, 1221, 
1174, 1070, 1059, 969, 982, 1059, 1009, 1011, 999, 969, 1042, 
1004, 1133, 1249, 1380, 1519, 1746, 1907, 2053, 2173, 2412, 2764, 
2742, 2990, 3085, 2576, 3108, 2990, 2972, 3360, 3625, 3257, 3375, 
4520, 5707, 8206, 7994, 6058, 5132, 4153, 3054, 2427, 2212, 2050, 
1655, 1755, 2048, 4878, 3341, 2561, 2464, 2158, 1881, 1843, 1864, 
1970, 1799, 1515, 1473, 1793, 1878, 1919, 1854, 1977, 2500, 3608, 
5708, 8518, 10915, 13458, 12567, 10789, 8682, 6933, 6048, 4972, 
4132, 3323, 3362, 3145, 2976, 3181), .Tsp = c(2004, 2009.98076923077, 
52), class = "ts")

> StructTS(z,"level") 

Call:
StructTS(x = z, type = "level")

Variances:
  level  epsilon  
 403733        0  

>data(Nile)
>StructTS(Nile,"level")

Call:
StructTS(x = Nile, type = "level")

Variances:
  level  epsilon  
   1469    15099
```

Answer (score 1):

dV is the variance of the observation error. It is not uncommon to find dV=0; see for example in the help for command **StructTS** the following comment:

> ```
>  Optimization of structural models is a lot harder than many of the
>  references admit. For example, the 'AirPassengers' data are
>  considered in Brockwell & Davis (1996): their solution appears to
>  be a local maximum, but nowhere near as good a fit as that
>  produced by 'StructTS'.  It is quite common to find fits with one
>  or more variances zero, and this can include sigma^2_eps.
> ```